# Is it possible to open and align 4 windows on a monitor using a batch/powershell script?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, batch-file

On windows10 I can manually open and align up to 4 windows on a single virtual desktop:

[image: 4 windows aligned on screen]

I tend to do that very often, I even have two layers of this on a screen, one layer with folders and the other with powershell consoles pointing at the same disk-location.

The issue is, that whenever windows10 has one of its fits and wants to restart, I have to reopen about a dozen folders & consoles to continue work. While this is meanwhile routine and hardly takes more than a few minutes, it still takes more than a few minutes and is a dreadful task I feel should be automated.

**Q**: Is there a way to automate this opening & aligning windows with a batch or powershell script?

Comment: Yes. Complete answer at [so] - [How can a batch file run a program and set the position and size of the window?](//stackoverflow.com/q/10392620)

Answer (score 0):

There are a ton of solutions for this but [this code](https://github.com/stefanstranger/PowerShell/blob/master/WinKeys.ps1) helps make this achievable without third party tools. We unfortunately cannot use [SendKeys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys(v=vs.110).aspx) because the `Win` key is unavailable.

This is a little hacky. Ideally you'd want to query the target monitor's resolution and start each process with the desired pixel position.

```
# stuff needed to send keystrokes
$source = @"
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace KeyboardSend
{
    public class KeyboardSend
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, int dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);
        private const int KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 1;
        private const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 2;
        public static void KeyDown(Keys vKey)
        {
            keybd_event((byte)vKey, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
        }
        public static void KeyUp(Keys vKey)
        {
            keybd_event((byte)vKey, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
        }
    }
}
"@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $source -ReferencedAssemblies "System.Windows.Forms"

# the arrow key combinations (0 = Left Up, 1 = Left Down, 2 = Right Up, 3 = Right Down)
$LR = @('Left','Left','Right','Right')
$UD = @('Up','Down','Up','Down')

# edit the sleep value as needed.
$sleepMS = 200

# start a process, move it in the next desirable position, x4
0..3 | % {

    Start-Process powershell
    # if we don't wait for the process to open, we might not have focus.
    Sleep -Milliseconds $sleepMS
    [KeyboardSend.KeyboardSend]::KeyDown("LWin")
    [KeyboardSend.KeyboardSend]::KeyDown($LR[$_])
    Sleep -Milliseconds $sleepMS
    [KeyboardSend.KeyboardSend]::KeyDown($UD[$_])
    [KeyboardSend.KeyboardSend]::KeyUp("LWin")
    Sleep -Milliseconds $sleepMS
    [KeyboardSend.KeyboardSend]::KeyDown("Escape")

}
```

[List of available keys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys(v=vs.110).aspx).